# Creating client-side callbacks for hover tracking images in Dash (revised)

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash, client-side

My last question, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034665/create-client-side-callback-for-hover-tracking-in-dash) may have been too time-consuming to answer (and got no answers), so this is a major revision on that question. What I have now in app.py is:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from dash.dependencies import ClientsideFunction, Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from PIL import Image

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server =  app.server

# In reality, there are 50 screenshot images with non-sequential indexes
urls = ["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EW8GhG_XkAEOyAh.jpg",
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CqzwpPnWEAAiGjW.jpg"]

def url_to_fig(url):
    rgb_arr = np.array(Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw))
    fig = px.imshow(rgb_arr)
    fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
    fig.update_layout(
        dragmode=False, width=800, height=800)
    fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='none', hovertemplate=None)
    return fig

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='ss-idx', data=0),
    dcc.Graph(id='ss-img', figure=url_to_fig(urls[0]), config = {"displayModeBar": False}),
    html.Button("Next", id='next-button', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Store(id='hoverdata', data=[]), # Place to append new hoverdata
    dcc.Store(id='blank-output')
])



app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(namespace="clientside", function_name="collect_hoverdata"),
    Output('blank-output', 'data'),
    Input('ss-img', 'hoverData')
)


app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(nclicks) {
        to_return = img_hover_data.slice();
        img_hover_data = [];
        return to_return;
    }
    """,
    Output("hoverdata", "data"),
    Input('next-button', 'n_clicks')
)



# Change to client side callback (in JavaScript)
@app.callback(
    [Output('ss-idx', 'data'),
     Output('ss-img', 'figure')],
    [Input('next-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('hoverdata', 'data'),
     State('ss-idx', 'data')]
)
def add_to_hoverdata(next_clicks, hoverdata, ss_idx):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if not ctx.triggered:
        raise PreventUpdate

        # Add hoverdata and screenshot index to mysql database (code not shown)
    print(len(hoverdata))
    if next_clicks < len(urls):
        new_idx = ss_idx + 1
        return new_idx, url_to_fig(urls[new_idx]) # Reset hoverdata
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and then in assets/hovertracker.js, I added this function:

```
var img_hover_data = [];

window.dash_clientside = Object.assign({}, window.dash_clientside, {
    clientside: {
        collect_hoverdata: function(hover_point) {
            var points_array = hover_point.points;
            var points = alert(points_array[0])
            var x = points.x;
            var y = points.y;
            var time = Date.now();
            img_hover_data.push([x, y, time]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
})
```

The idea here that the actual figure is still created with plotly express, and then whenever it's hovered over, it will accumulate the hover data client-side inside `img_hover_data` (a client-side global variable) until the `next` button is pushed, at which time it will refresh the page with a new figure (done with a normal callback) and the value of `img_hover_data` will be an empty list again (clientside callback).

In doing this, I receive the error whenever the image is hovered over:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`

My new (hopefully simpler) question is: why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I was receiving this error as well, and for me the solution was to define js functions rather than just raw js code (I was just trying to log to the console). Obv this doesn't seem to be the issue for you, but figured I'd share. A thought though: since you're running two clientside callbacks two different ways, have you determined which is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I just found your first question and gave it a shot, so apologies for spamming you with two answers.

The error that you are getting is most likely related to `img_hover_data` in your second clientside callback. It is a bit dangerous to define it in the global scope if you intend to manipulate it in Dash callbacks, so one quick fix could be to have it as a `dcc.Store` component data and pass it to both clientside callbacks. There won't be any performance cost of doing it because the data will be in the clientside in both cases.

Two observations regarding your first callback:

1. Dash will evaluate callbacks when the app starts, so whether you prevent the callback execution (using `prevent_initial_update=True`), or you have to deal with an `undefined` hover_point. The way to prevent updates in clientside is through `dash_clientside.no_updates` (more info [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/preventupdate-for-clientside-callbacks/24431/8)).
2. In this part:

```js
var points_array = hover_point.points;
var points = alert(points_array[0])
var x = points.x;
var y = points.y;
```

Another exception will be raised because `points` is undefined (`alert` returns `undefined`), so you want to change it to `var x = points_array[0].x` and the same for `y`.